# Rotating Ellipse Curve in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

### Goal

I am trying to create an EllipseCurve (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/curves/EllipseCurve) on which a camera should move.

### What I did to achive the goal?

This is the code for the ellipse so far.

```js
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
    0,0,
    1, 1,
    0, 2 * Math.PI,
    false,
    1.57
)

const points = curve.getPoints( 50 );
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );


var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xffffff } );

// Create the final object to add to the scene
var curveObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

scene.add(curveObject);
```

I can see it in the scene like this:

[image: Circle being in x-axes]

### The Problem

I tried to rotate the Ellipse Curve 90 degree arround the x axis clockwise. As I understood from the documentation, the last parameter of the defining function should rotate it.

```js
const curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
    0,  0,            // ax, aY
    10, 10,           // xRadius, yRadius
    0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
    false,            // aClockwise
    0                 // aRotation
);
```

Thank you in advance for you answer. I am quite new to Three.js so sorry if this question might be stupid :D

Comment: The last parameter rotates the curve around Z-axis, thus the curve itself is on XY-plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the aRotation, angle-rotation, will affect the local origin of other angle settings for this curve. It is not the overall ellipse rotation, but the orientation of any offset relative to default. A different starting point. It would turn a Pac-Man mouth into a backwards Pac-Man mouth at +/- 180-degrees. To rotate the overall curve in world-space, use one of the various methods available, such as curve.rotation.set(0,1,0) or rotation.y += 1. Please refer to documentation for specific variants of rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Get a point on the curve and apply a matrix4 to it.

Here is a concept of how you can do it (see the lines with `cam` in the animation loop, better to watch with "Full page"):

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.134.0";
import {
  OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.134.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-10, 10, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.autoClear = false;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
})

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

let grid = new THREE.GridHelper();
grid.position.y = -5;
scene.add(grid);

let obj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 0), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
scene.add(obj);

let curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(0, 0, 10, 5);

let line = new THREE.Line(new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curve.getSpacedPoints(100)), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "yellow"
}));
line.rotation.x = -Math.PI * 0.25;
line.rotation.z = Math.PI * 0.125;
line.position.x = 5;
scene.add(line);

let cam = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, 1, 1.5, 25);
let camHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(cam);
scene.add(camHelper);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();
let v = new THREE.Vector3();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

  let t = (clock.getElapsedTime() * 0.05) % 1;
  
  // magic is in these lines //////////////////
  cam.position.copy(curve.getPointAt(t, v));
  cam.position.applyMatrix4(line.matrixWorld);
  cam.lookAt(obj.position);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////

  renderer.clear();
  renderer.setViewport(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  renderer.setViewport(0, innerHeight - 256, 256, 256);
  renderer.render(scene, cam);
})

</script>
```